# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word Vue.js

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js

I have a Vue instance

```
var interface = new Vue(
{...}
)
```

And i created a class called MyCustomTooltip

```
class MyCustomTooltip {

    constructor(array_info,vue_instance) {
        this.tooltip_info = array_info;
        this.vue_instance = vue_instance

        console.log(interface)

    }
}
```

I try to use 'interface' instance inside some methods in MyCustomTooltip class, but when i reference it I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word`. I fixed the issue by passing the vue instance to the constructor, but now i have to send the `interface` variable every time i create a new MyCustomTooltip instance.

Does anyone know why is this happenning ?
How can i fix this?
Am i taking the wrong approach?

Comment: `interface` is a reserved word, you can't use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TypeScript? If so, `interface` is a reserved keyword used for declaring an interface https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

A simple fix would be to give your variable a different name. Even something as simple as changing it to `myInterface` should solve the problem.

If you are not using TypeScript though, the error you're seeing is unexpected.

Comment: I'm using javascript, but i changed the var. name to ''app''  & that fixed the problem